# React native navigation.state.params always undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, flowtype

I am fairly new to React native, and I have bought a template called sketch elements to get me started which is using Flow for it's type checking.

https://react-native.shop/elements

I would like to pass a parameter while navigating, however the param is always undefined.

This is my code in my first component - I would like to navigate to the navigateTo component (in this case Photos) passing in the level object

```
navigate(navigateTo: string, level: object) {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate(navigateTo, { level });
}
```

My other component looks as follows, console log always returns undefined.  Looking through the other examples this looks identical to what has been achieved before but I am obviously missing something.

```
type PhotosProps = NavigationProps<> & {
    level: object
};

export default class Photos extends React.Component<NavigationProps<PhotosProps>> {
    render(): React.Node {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        console.log( navigation.state.params);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can access parameters passed into `react-navigation` library by using `const level = navigation.getParam('level')`. Docs on passing parameters: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this also returns undefined as well?

Comment: Can you try logging the `level` variable before you perform `navigation.navigate(navigateTo, { level });` to make sure it's not undefined there?

Comment: sure, it gives - Object { "colour": "#83de64",
 "friendlyName": "Level 1",
 "level": 6,
 "name": "1",
"theme": "Level1",
}

Comment: That's weird. Can you log the entire navigation state (`navigation.state` without params) in Photos render method? Also try logging it in its componentDidMount for a good measure.

Comment: Also which version of `react-navigation` package are you using?

Comment: I know... in my previous projects that I made myself your solution worked, just this one with Flow I cannot work out.  "react-navigation": "3.0.0-rc.4"

Comment: The latest release is actually `react-navigation@3.0.8`. So not sure, maybe this is a bug. Try updating to the latest version. You can check what the latest version of any package is by running `npm show <package_name`.

Comment: I've done a test and going directly to the component worked.., it's when I pass it through a createStackNavigator then it stops working - do you know if there is extra bits I need to add to make it work with that?

Comment: AFAIK if you get a `navigation` property set up in your component, it should definitely work. Perhaps try setting up a few default parameters and see if you're able to extract them from the navigation? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#params I'm not sure about the extend of helpfulness of this however, but you'll at least be able to make sure you can actually access any params there at all.

Answer (score 0):

If using react-navigation v5, then

```
route.params?.someParam ?? 'defaultValue';
```